# Using Timer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I use Timer in VB.Net?  I want to repeat a statement after every 5 seconds but timer event offers only `timer_tick()` and `timer_disposed()`

In which event I can write my required code?

Comment: Tick.  Like "tick-tock", the sound that a clock makes.  They didn't consider "Cuckoo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write your event in the `timer_tick()`.

It's worth noting that your timer tick is in Milliseconds (ms) so you'll need to set its property to 5000 for 5 seconds.

You'll also need to start the timer (`timer1.start`) (you can do this on form load if you want the action to start from when the form is first loaded) and then put your loop in the `timer_tick()` section :)

Have a look [here](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6150796.html) for a rudimentary explanation:

Answer (score 1):

You will want to use the `Tick` event. When the `Timer` is enabled, it will be raised on the interval defined by the `Interval` property.

Answer (score 0):

The timer_tick method is called in time-interval You set. Your code should go there.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the Timer's Tick Event and write in the required statement which should repeat every 5 seconds there. Have a look at the following example:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.tick.aspx